# How to set a breakpoint in a record (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, record

Java 14 has brought in a new type of object called a record, I have found that eclipse does not allow me to set breakpoints in it.

I am guessing that eclipse does not recognize record as a java class and therefore does not allow breakpoints.

I can debug into the record through the calling code. But I would rather be able to set the breakpoint in the class.
I am using eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers - 2021-06

just to make clear, this is a java class with methods, but eclipse will not allow breakpoints in any of the methods.

. I was hoping that someone might of had a similar problem, and there is something you need to set in eclipse so that eclipse knows this record is a legitimate java class

Comment: What do you mean you cant set a breakpoint? Breakpoint to what action? Construction? One of the getter methods? Something else? Please elaborate and show some screenshots to clarify, thanks.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @Zabuzard Doesn't seem unclear to me. The record keyword, which is new to me, seems to autogenerate getters/setters and other common POJO methods. So the question is how to set breakpoints in this type of structure which has only generated code that is not visible to the user in the IDE.

Comment: "So the question is how to set breakpoints in this type of structure which has only generated code that is not visible to the user in the IDE" - is it really? To me, you are assuming answers to all the questions I wrote in my first comment.

Comment: Its not generated code. Its a new type of class called a record. It has methods just like any class. But I when try to set a breakpoint in a method it wont set the breakpoint.
I was hoping that someone might of had a similar problem, and there is something you need to se in eclipse so that eclipse knows this record is a legitimate java class,

Comment: eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers - 2021-06

Comment: Retry it with the current release.

Comment: Ok I will download the very latests it may handle record

Comment: @Tony Can you please share some screenshots to clarify where exactly you want to put a breakpoint? I am not convinced that Eclipse cant put breakpoints - I rather think that you misunderstand records and where to put the breakpoint to in order for it to work. Otherwise your question might soon get closed for being unclear.

Comment: Records are an official (non-preview) feature since JDK 16. I tried with both, JDK 16 and JDK 17, and Eclipse 2021-12 and breakpoints in record methods worked.